# How to compute the norm of this particular bounded linear functional?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

On the Hilbert space $l^2$, let $f$ be the functional defined by $$f(x):= \sum_{j=1}^\infty \alpha_j \xi_j$$ for each $x:=(\xi_j)_{j=1}^\infty$ in $l^2$, where $a:= (\alpha_j)_{j=1}^\infty$ is a fixed element in $l^2$.

While this functional is linear and bounded, how to compute the norm?

What is the situation if instead of $l^2$ we take $l^p$ for an arbitrary but fixed $p \geq 1$?

Comment: Take your favourite textbook on functional analysis, and there you will find the description of dual to $\ell^p$ or $L^p$, including the norm.

Answer (score 1):

For the case of $\ell_2$, apply Cauchy-Schwarz to obtain
 $$|f(x)| 
  = \left|\sum_{j=1}^\infty \alpha_j x_j\right|
  = |\langle \alpha,x\rangle|
  \leq \|\alpha\|\|x\|.$$
Hence $\|f\|\leq\|\alpha\|$. To show $\|f\|=\|\alpha\|$, observe $f(\alpha)=\|\alpha\|^2$.

For general $\ell_p$ spaces, [Hölder's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality) will be useful.

Comment: For the case $\ell_p$ you need $a \in \ell_q$ where $\frac1p + \frac1q = 1$.

Comment: What if $a$ still belongs to $\ell^p$ instead of $\ell^q$? Do we have a way of determining the norm in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Observe that in case of the Hilbert space $l^2$ your functional is of the form
$$x\mapsto \langle x, \alpha\rangle.$$
Now use Riesz's representation theorem for Hilbert spaces. The norm of this functional is $\|\alpha\|$. Note that $(l^2)^*$ and $l^2$ are isometricaly isomorphic.

There are analogous representation theorems for other spaces $l^p$ or $L^p$, $p\neq2$. Keep in mind that those spaces are not Hilbert spaces.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't right now recall the Riesz's representation theorem for Hilbert spaces.